# Trino implement a function like regexp_split_to_table()?

Tags: sql, split, hive, trino

Everyone,

I am new to Trino, and I find no function in Trino like `regexp_split_to_table()` in GreenPlum or PostgreSQL. How can I approach that?

```
select regexp_split_to_table( sensor_type, E',+' ) as type from hydrology.device_info;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [regexp_split(string, pattern)](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html) function, returns array, you can [unnest](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) it.

Demo:

```
select s.str as original_str, u.str as exploded_value
from
(select 'one,two,,,three' as str)s
cross join unnest(regexp_split(s.str,',+')) as u(str)
```

Result:

```
original_str     exploded_value 
one,two,,,three  one
one,two,,,three  two
one,two,,,three  three
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found no unnest() and regexp_split() in Trino,And Trino have not supported the UDTF yet. Thanks anyway.

Comment: O I try it, It works even no idea in the documents。Thanks！

Comment: @LiAnqian Added links to the documentation

Comment: I find it, Thanks.